# JavaFX default focused button in Alert Dialog

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Since jdk 8u40, I'm using the new `javafx.scene.control.Alert` API to display a confirmation dialog. In the example below, "Yes" button is focused by default instead of "No" button:

```
public boolean showConfirmDialog(String title, String header, String content, AlertType alertType) {
    final Alert alert = new Alert(alertType);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(header);
    alert.setContentText(content);

    alert.getButtonTypes().clear();
    alert.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);

    final Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    return result.get() == ButtonType.YES;
}
```

And I don't know how to change it.

EDIT :

Here a screenshot of the result where "Yes" button is focused by default :

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am not sure if the following is the way to usually do this, but you could change the default button by looking up the buttons and setting the default-behavior yourself:

```
public boolean showConfirmDialog(String title, String header, String content, AlertType alertType) {
    final Alert alert = new Alert(alertType);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(header);
    alert.setContentText(content);

    alert.getButtonTypes().clear();
    alert.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);

    //Deactivate Defaultbehavior for yes-Button:
    Button yesButton = (Button) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( ButtonType.YES );
    yesButton.setDefaultButton( false );

    //Activate Defaultbehavior for no-Button:
    Button noButton = (Button) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton( ButtonType.NO );
    noButton.setDefaultButton( true );

    final Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    return result.get() == ButtonType.YES;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A simple function thanks to crusam:

```
private static Alert setDefaultButton ( Alert alert, ButtonType defBtn ) {
   DialogPane pane = alert.getDialogPane();
   for ( ButtonType t : alert.getButtonTypes() )
      ( (Button) pane.lookupButton(t) ).setDefaultButton( t == defBtn );
   return alert;
}
```

Usage:

```
final Alert alert = new Alert( 
         AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "You sure?", ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO );
if ( setDefaultButton( alert, ButtonType.NO ).showAndWait()
         .orElse( ButtonType.NO ) == ButtonType.YES ) {
   // User selected the non-default yes button
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a look at (private) `ButtonBarSkin` class, there is a method called `doButtonOrderLayout()` that performs the layout of the buttons, based in some default OS behavior.

Inside of it, you can read this:

> /* now that all buttons have been placed, we need to ensure focus is
>      set on the correct button. [...] If so, we request focus onto this default
>      button. */

Since `ButtonType.YES` is the default button, it will be the one focused.

So @ymene answer is correct: you can change the default behavior and then the one focused will be `NO`.

Or you can just avoid using that method, by setting `BUTTON_ORDER_NONE` in the `buttonOrderProperty()`. Now the first button will have the focus, so you need to place first the `NO` button.

```
alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(ButtonType.NO, ButtonType.YES);

ButtonBar buttonBar=(ButtonBar)alert.getDialogPane().lookup(".button-bar");
buttonBar.setButtonOrder(ButtonBar.BUTTON_ORDER_NONE);
```

Note that `YES` will still have the default behavior: This means `NO` can be selected with the space bar (focused button), while `YES` will be selected if you press enter (default button).

[image: Alert dialog]

Or you can change also the default behavior following @crusam answer.